# C Yahtzee simulator takes insane amount of rolls in Windows, not in Linux

Tags: c, linux, random, seed

I wanted to type some "easy" code messing with rand and srand functions, and I tried to program a simulator of Yahtzee rolls. It randomly rolls 5 dice, and if they match, it prints you've got a Yahtzee and how many re-rolls it took to get it. I typed this in an Ubuntu VM on a Windows. Works fine and gets reasonable results (between 1 and 4000) of rerolls. However, when I take the same code to Windows, it ALWAYS takes like 50 milion rerolles to score a Yahtzee. Why is this happening? Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    int dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, count=0, e=1;

    while(e==1){
        srand(time(NULL)+rand());
        dice1 = rand () % (6) + 1;

        srand(time(NULL)+rand());
        dice2 = rand () % (6) + 1;

        srand(time(NULL)+rand());
        dice3 = rand () % (6) + 1;

        srand(time(NULL)+rand());
        dice4 = rand () % (6) + 1;

        srand(time(NULL)+rand());
        dice5 = rand () % (6) + 1;

        if(dice1 == dice2 && dice2 == dice3 && dice3 == dice4 && dice4 == dice5){
            printf("\tYAHTZEE! of %i's\n\tIt took %i rolls\n", dice1, count);
            if(count >= 2920) printf("+++LESS THAN A 10%% CHANCE!+++\n");
            count = 0;
            scanf("%i", &e);
        } else count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to use only the first srand but it keeps happening.

Comment: I've already tried that, will edit it now. It keeps happening, it still takes too long to get a Yahtzee roll. Actually, what's wrong with refreshing the seed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one second, `time(NULL)` will return the same number. The same seed will produce the same series of random numbers. Call `srand(time(NULL))` once as one of the first statements.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    int dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, count=0, e=1;

    srand(time(NULL));//call here outside loop so it isn't called again too soon
    while(e==1){
        dice1 = rand () % (6) + 1;
        dice2 = rand () % (6) + 1;
        dice3 = rand () % (6) + 1;
        dice4 = rand () % (6) + 1;
        dice5 = rand () % (6) + 1;
        if(dice1 == dice2 && dice2 == dice3 && dice3 == dice4 && dice4 == dice5){
            printf("\tYAHTZEE! of %i's\n\tIt took %i rolls\n", dice1, count);
            if(count >= 2920) printf("+++LESS THAN A 10%% CHANCE!+++\n");
            count = 0;
            scanf("%i", &e);
        } else count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works now, thanks! However, why did this work in Linux from the beginning?